# Entity Framework query too slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework and love the simplicity but am having some trouble with speed. I think I might be using the lazy loading incorrectly but having a hard time wrapping my head around it. I have separated my data model layer and business entity layer, and use a function to create the business entity from my data model. In this function I iterate over the different nested entities to create their corresponding models. Ok, enough rambling here is some code:

IM_ITEM.cs (Product data model)

```
public partial class IM_ITEM
{
    public IM_ITEM()
    {
        this.IM_INV = new HashSet<IM_INV>();
        this.IM_BARCOD = new HashSet<IM_BARCOD>();
        this.IM_GRID_DIM_1 = new HashSet<IM_GRID_DIM_1>();
        this.IM_GRID_DIM_2 = new HashSet<IM_GRID_DIM_2>();
        this.IM_GRID_DIM_3 = new HashSet<IM_GRID_DIM_3>();
        this.IM_PRC = new HashSet<IM_PRC>();
    }

    public string ITEM_NO { get; set; }
    public string DESCR { get; set; }
    // many more properties...

    public virtual ICollection<IM_INV> IM_INV { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IM_BARCOD> IM_BARCOD { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IM_GRID_DIM_1> IM_GRID_DIM_1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IM_GRID_DIM_2> IM_GRID_DIM_2 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IM_GRID_DIM_3> IM_GRID_DIM_3 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IM_PRC> IM_PRC { get; set; }
}
```

Business entity creation method:

```
public static ProductEntity FromEfObject(IM_ITEM obj) {
    var product = new ProductEntity {
        ItemNumber = obj.ITEM_NO,
        StyleNumber = obj.VEND_ITEM_NO,
        Title = obj.DESCR_UPR,
        LongName = obj.ADDL_DESCR_1,
        ShortDescription = obj.DESCR,
        VendorCode = obj.ITEM_VEND_NO,
        Quarter = obj.ATTR_COD_2,
        Color = obj.PROF_ALPHA_2,
        Markdown = obj.PRC_1,
        Price = obj.REG_PRC ?? 0,
        Status = obj.STAT,
        DepartmentCode = obj.ATTR_COD_1,
        DepartmentDigit = obj.ATTR_COD_1.Substring(0, 1),
        MixAndMatch = obj.MIX_MATCH_COD,
        Inventory = new Inventory(obj.IM_INV),
        Sizes = new List<ProductSize>(),
        Widths = new List<ProductSize>(),
        Lengths = new List<ProductSize>(),
        Barcodes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    };


    if (obj.IM_PRC.Any()) {
        var price = obj.IM_PRC.First();
        product.DnsPrice2 = price.PRC_2.GetValueOrDefault();
        product.DnsPrice3 = price.PRC_3.GetValueOrDefault();
    }

    foreach (var barcode in obj.IM_BARCOD) {
        product.Barcodes.Add(barcode.DIM_1_UPR, barcode.BARCOD);
    }

    foreach (var size in obj.IM_GRID_DIM_1) {
        product.Sizes.Add(ProductSize.FromEfObject(size));
    }

    foreach (var width in obj.IM_GRID_DIM_2) {
        product.Widths.Add(ProductSize.FromEfObject(width));
    }

    foreach (var length in obj.IM_GRID_DIM_3) {
        product.Lengths.Add(ProductSize.FromEfObject(length));
    }

    if (!product.Sizes.Any()) {
        product.Sizes.Add(new ProductSize());
    }

    if (!product.Widths.Any()) {
        product.Widths.Add(new ProductSize());
    }

    if (!product.Lengths.Any()) {
        product.Lengths.Add(new ProductSize());
    }

    return product;
}
```

And my method to retrieve the model:

```
public ProductEntity GetProductById(string itemNumber, int storeNumber) {
    var product = _unitOfWork
        .GetProductRepository(storeNumber)
        .GetQueryable()
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ITEM_NO == itemNumber);

    return product == null ? null : ProductEntity.FromEfObject(product);
}
```

And the GetQueryable method:

```
internal DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;
public GenericRepository(TContext context)
{
    Context = context;
    DbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
}

public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryable()
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;
    return query;
}
```

A little more info.. I used database first modeling to create my data model, and the database I am testing against doesn't have a ton of data. Also, I tried using `.Include()` in my `GetProductById` method to load (eagerly I believe) but the slowed it down even further.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? Or is using EF going to be slow for a query like this.

EDIT: To prevent lazy loading I updated my query to:

```
    public ProductEntity GetProductById(string itemNumber, int storeNumber) {
        var product = _unitOfWork
            .GetProductRepository(storeNumber)
            .GetQueryable()
            .Include(p => p.IM_INV.Select(i => i.IM_INV_CELL))
            .Include(p => p.IM_BARCOD)
            .Include(p => p.IM_GRID_DIM_1)
            .Include(p => p.IM_GRID_DIM_2)
            .Include(p => p.IM_GRID_DIM_3)
            .Include(p => p.IM_PRC)
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ITEM_NO == itemNumber);

        return product == null ? null : ProductEntity.FromEfObject(product);
    }
```

When tracing, this gives me just one big nasty query that takes longer than using the lazy loading http://pastebin.com/LT1vTETb

Comment: What is your implementation of `_unitOfWork.GetProductRepository(storeNumber).GetQueryable()` because if that part is wrong, it could be that EF queries your entire product table into memory before your `FirstOrDefault` is executed, and thus slowing it down.

Comment: Updated with that code.. thanks!

Comment: Is Sql Server your back end repository? If so use Sql Server Profiler to see what is actually executed on the server. If there are multiple statements (like suggested by @SynerCoder) then it could very well be a piece of code you are not showing us that would materialize the entire table before executing the FirstOrDefault. Either way use that to see what is executing. If that looks correct then start analyzing (tuning) the query, if it looks wrong start digging through the code.

Comment: Does the `storeNumber` affect the DbContext that is loaded, or is it part of a query? CQ, your implementation of `GetQueryable` is for a generic repository, but how does a product repository look.

Comment: You need to identify exactly _where_ it's slow.  Get a decent profiler (or add a bunch of `Stopwatch` calls) to identify where your app is spending the most time overall.  Then tackle the slowest parts to get them as fast as possible.  I see nothing glaringly obvious from what you're posted.

Comment: That affects the DbContext that is loaded.. Different databases for different stores. I'll check out the sql profiler to see if I can get a better picture.. thanks for the tip. I did some basic timing stuff to see what was slow and it seemed pretty evenly distributed through the `FromEfObject()` method.. one second for the IM_PRC block, one second for the barcode foreach etc

Comment: I don't see anything weird then, my guess is that the slow part is in `ProductEntity.FromEfObject`.

Comment: With lazy loading, when you test `obj.IM_PRC.Any()` followed by a call to `obj.IM_PRC.First()`, you are doing *two* extra calls to the database.

Comment: @HansKesting No, because the first call (`obj.IM_PRC.Any()`) loads the entities into to context and marks the collection as loaded.

Comment: @TroyCosentino as a test, what sort of performance do you get if you map only the direct properties and no foreign keys? What about with the Includes below? Then try adding foreign key mappings back in one-at-a-time to see if you can identify what is slow

Comment: Tracing it I am seeing one query for each object I am using (IM_PRC, IM_BARCOD etc). So that looks good.. After each query there is an 'Audit Logout' that has a duration of around 10000 for each query (much higher than the times of the query) but from searching it looks like I shouldn't worry about that. I am finding that it is very inconsistent - usually the web service takes 6-10 seconds but every once in awhile will be 1.5 seconds or 15 seconds. Nothing else is hitting the database so I am a little confused on that.. will keep digging

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your query to avoid lazy loading. In this case, when you load an object from the database, you know you're going to have to map almost the entire object graph to memory. You're going to need to look up all of those foreign keys later anyway - it's faster to do it all as one query rather than letting lazy loading do the work. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) for more information.

It should look something like this:

```
public ProductEntity GetProductById(string itemNumber, int storeNumber) {
    var product = _unitOfWork
        .GetProductRepository(storeNumber)
        .GetQueryable()
        .Include(p => p.IM_BARCOD)
        .Include(p => p.IM_GRID_DIM_1)
        .Include(p => p.IM_GRID_DIM_2)
        .Include(p => p.IM_GRID_DIM_3)
        .Include(p => p.IM_PRC)
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ITEM_NO == itemNumber);

    return product == null ? null : ProductEntity.FromEfObject(product);
}
```

Note that if these foreign keys have their own foreign keys (i.e. IM_BARCOD has a collection of IM_OtherType) which you also need to map to your ProductEntity model, you should also include those. You can do it in line like this:

```
.Include(p => p.IM_BARCOD.Select(b => b.IM_OTHERTYPE))
```

Comment: In this case I would want to do .Where(p => p.ITEM_NO == itemNumber) before the includes, correct? I tested that and it went from ~8 seconds to about 20 seconds so I went back to debugging without the includes

Comment: No, you don't need the Where before. With EF, all of this code gets translated into a single SQL query - it's not actually executed in C#. The order of the statements doesn't matter since it turns into the same SQL query at the end.

Comment: Ok that's good to know.. I knew it compiled to one query but didn't know it was smart enough to order things.. Sort of side question but if I had several Where statements does it optimize the order for me?

Comment: Having multiple where statements is semantically the same as having multiple conditions with && in a single where. EF may not optimize this itself, but the Query Optimizer of your DBMS most likely will (MS SQL Server does, for example)